# Will the ABE scheme based on RSA generate a constant secret key better than schemes based on elliptic curve cryptography?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, abe

We know in terms of security level, that an ECC key is stronger than an RSA one (e.g. a 160-bit ECC key would be equivalent to a 1024-bit key in RSA). If I can generate a constant secret key based on RSA, does that mean my scheme performance could be better than the scheme based on ECC?

Comment: ...what? All those words are meaningful on their own, but I can't make any sense of what you're actually trying to ask.

Comment: if we have ABE scheme that generate constant secret key then, I can skip the advantage of ECC in term of less key size ? Hopefully the idea of the question become more clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "constant secret key"?

Comment: I mean the secret key is constant so it does not effect by different parameters like number of attribute so it is always same size.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of constant a constant secret key is either just a secret key or not secret. One case doesn't change anything the other is not useful.